# Since installing VS 2012, I'm getting intermittent PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: asp.net, iis, pipeline, integrated-pipeline-mode

I've recently installed VS 2012 and .net Framework 4.5, and everything is mostly ok, except that I occasionally get the error:
This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

I of course have Managed pipeline mode: Integrated in IIS.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    var st = new StackTrace(true);
    string message = String.Format("Redirect to url: {0}, Stack Trace:\r\n{1}", url, st);
    Trace.TraceInformation(message);
}

protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new OurAspTraceListener(Context));
}
```

And the Custom Trace listener is pretty simple.

```
private class OurAspTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private readonly HttpContext _context;
        public OurAspTraceListener(HttpContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _context.Trace.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        public override void Write(string message)
        {
            _context.Trace.Write(message); // it's throwing here.
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            _context.Trace.Write(message);
        }
    }
```

It's really weird because if I just hit refresh it continues without any problem.

Any help would is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Please post as much of your web.config as you feel comfortable posting. Especially the runtime and compilation elements. Also clarify what server you are using. (development, iisexpress, local iis)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IIS do you have ?
If you use IIS 7, make sure you have the application pool type set to integrated and not classic. The integrated pipeline mode is IIS 7 specific.